# Вывод списка из БД с выбранным жлементом

Tags: база-данных

Помогите плз! Есть 2 таблицы в БД "teplo_db" и "category" в первой находятся товары, во второй список брендов для товаров. П.С вторая таблица нужна для выбора бренда при внесении товара или для изменения при редактировании. При редактировании товара не могу сделать - чтоб в выпадающем списке по умолчанию был бренд товара, а не первый бренд в списке. Например: хочу изменить смартфон Samsung на Sony а по умолчанию выводится первый бренд из списка а не реальный бренд товара.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прикрепите схему бд, как связаны таблицы?

Comment: они не связаны, это разные таблицы (они не зависят друг от друга). Главная таблица в которой хранятся все товары - "teplo_db" (название, бренд, фото и.т.д), вспомогательная "category" там бренды и прочая информация для внесения товаров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить в тэг option

```
if ($result_category["id"] == $result["category_id"]) echo " selected";
```

чтоб получилось

```
<option value="1" selected>
```

category_id надо заменить на поле, которое связывает с таблицей category.

Добавлю с кодом:

```
do {
    echo '<option value="'.$result_category['id'].'"';
    if ($result_category["brand"] == $result["brand"]) echo ' selected';
    echo '>'.$result_category["id"].' '.$result_category["brand"].'</option>\r\n';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня по прежнему не получается. Если не сложно напишите пожалуйста часть кода, который нужно заменить.

Comment: Какое поле в таблице teplo_bd ссылается на идентификатор бренда из category?

Comment: Поле "brand" есть обеих таблицах. Я его подставлял по вашему совету. Скорее всего проблема в том, что я не в то место пишу строки кода.

Comment: Т.е. teplo_bd хранит название бренда, а не id?

Comment: Добавил в ответ код

Comment: teplo_bd хранит id товара и название бренда. (это таблица в которой вся информация о товаре). Вторая таблица "category" хранит только полный список брендов из нее можно выбрать или поменять бренд товара, который будет сохранен о основную таблицу "teplo_bd".

Comment: Значит код, который я добавил в ответ должен сработать.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teplo_db WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  $category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY brand ASC",$link);   
  If (mysql_num_rows($category) > 0)
  {
  $result_category = mysql_fetch_array($category);
do {
    echo '
    <li><option value="'.$result_category['id'].'"';if ($result_category["brand"] == $result["brand"]) echo ' selected';echo '>
    '.$result_category["id"].' '.$result_category["brand"].'</option>\r\n
    </li>
    ';}
  while ($result_category = mysql_fetch_array($category));}}

Comment: Вот этот код выводит просто бренды списком в алфавитном порядке, но по прежнему не отображает "Бренд выбранного товара".

Comment: Все спасибо!!!! я разобрался!!! Я создал еще одну переменную от первой таблицы $row вставил ее в Ваш код и все заработало. Спасибо большое! Вы очень мне помогли!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Отлично! А про переменную - да, я тоже не заметил.